# Выдаёт ошибку и я не знаю, как вывод правильно оформить

Tags: python

Необходимо вывести на экран объём товаров в м^3 после расчёта объёма всех значений в формате числа. Но выдаёт ошибку invalid syntax
Мой код:

```
books = int (input("Количество книг: "))
stationery = int (input("Количество канцтоваров: "))
toys = int (input("Количество игрушек: "))
toys = input *2
stationery = input *1.5
books = input *3
volume = toys + stationery + books
print (float"Общий объём: {volume} м^3")
```

Comment: Почитайте для начала какой-нибудь учебник по питону. Хотя бы первую главу. Естественно, `invalid syntax`, у вас же ошибок больше, чем слов...

Comment: Слушайте, я всё понимаю, конечно, но у меня только в одной строчке ошибки. И я просто хотел спросить, что можно с этим сделать, чтобы учесть на будущее. Спасибо за совет, конечно, но это сейчас делу не поможет.

Comment: У вас не в одной строчке ошибки. Во-первых, вообще непонятно, что вы хотите от умножения функции на число. `input *2` — что это? В последней строке аргумент для `float` без скобок. Стиль кода никакой. Вот что в программе не так.

Comment: @Глеб, а зачем вообще `float` в последней стрке? :)  Как по мне, главная проблема данного "кода" -- непонятная связь между _количеством_ книг, канцтоваров и игрушек (подразумеваются _штуки_) и _объёмом_ в кубометрах.  У меня есть две книги и их объём составит 6 кубов, а для двух игрушек объём будет 4 куба?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде должно работать: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##JYxJCsJAEEX3nqJw093SCBqE4GGELAwGtRNiXEgIRAWnnVsXnsEBwSHmDL9OFFtdVdX/71U0SwahcaoqigOTSL@OI868xR0PQmnXHe9RdCmdTMfSH4VeIgMTTS0pcLDAC3de48ZzXuCCklLjjftZl4RSjSH5YUzfQA8pMCSlwBNv@/sqdFtp@t0nvHll7dL6J86/U@hWs/PvLcs5L3mDG55CO0qpjFD0nLqqKqfm1twP)

```
print(f"Общий объём: {sum(float(input(f'Количество {name}: '))*k for name,k in (('книг',2), ('канцтоваров',1.5), ('игрушек',3)))} м^3")
```

Comment: А вложенные `f`-строки — это нормально? По-моему, без внутренних можно спокойно обойтись. А то они сильно усложняют прочтение кода — на первый взгляд вообще непонятно в чем дело.

Comment: @Глеб, ну если исходить из того, что питон собирались допилить, чтобы вложенные f-строки можно было делать в одинаковых кавычках, должно быть нормально)))